# How to setup Three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

**Hello!**
I started learning three.js a few days ago, and I cannot find any information online that works about how you run a html file with three.js javascript coding.

This is how I have done:
I have a folder on my desktop named Threegame. Inside I have two files: 
 My html file with all my code, and the Three.min.js file

When I open my html file in my browser using Notepad++ ("run < launch in crome") nothing happens. And I dont think there is something wrong with my html code because when I use my code on Codecademy.com's code editor in their exercises it works and displays a three.mesh as a floor and the movements of the camera is working.

Here is my [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njux6r28icaswlx/mycode.html).
Feel free to change the code as you are trying to help me :)
**Tnx!**

Comment: After you do "Run > ..." in the browser window do "Tools > JavaScript console" and look at the error messages and tell us what they are.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/Elias/Documents/three.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /C:/Users/Elias/Documents/mycode.html:10

Comment: So the page could not find the location of the three.js library. Is that where you placed it? Is the path correct ?

Comment: Oops I had two copies of the same three.js. But the consol now shows:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/Users/Elias/Desktop/threegame/three.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /C:/Users/Elias/Desktop/threegame/gamecode.html:13

The path /C:/Users/Elias/Desktop/threegame/gamecode.html:13 is EXACTLY the right path for my html file

Comment: Is that the right path for three.js?

Comment: As I wrote at last (maybe you didnt notice) its the right path.
BUT IT WORKS NOW! :D 
I googled again and tried using this:
<script src="https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/Three.js"></script>

Tnx alot for trying to help me! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: if anything was useful would you consider giving some credit?

Comment: Sure! Can i +rep you or anything? I'm new to stackoverflow :P

Comment: You can +1 on any comment/answer you like.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it!